# How to enable local storage for cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to store the values in to the local storage in an hybrid app. When I run the app in desktop web browser, but when I run the same in the android device I am not able to see the same output as in web browser. I think it's not getting saved in local storage.

Is there any way i can solve this or do i have to enable the local storage?

Here's my code:

```
function deductBalance(){
    var str;
    var num_arr = [];
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.cost-block-deduct');
    elems.forEach(function(el) {
      var nums = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
      num_arr.push(nums)
    });
    console.log(num_arr);
    var alvar1 = (Number.parseInt(num_arr.join("")));
    localStorage.setItem("deducted", alvar1);
    window.location.href = "home.html"
}

function todaysExpenses(){
    document.getElementById("spent_points_today").innerHTML = localStorage.deducted ;
    document.getElementById("earned_points_today").innerHTML = localStorage.balance;
    document.getElementById("balance-remaining").innerHTML = localStorage.balance - localStorage.deducted;
    document.getElementById("balance-remaining-month").innerHTML = localStorage.balance - localStorage.deducted;
}
```

Comment: Check, if local storage is supported by browser or not.
 try {
        localStorage.setItem("mod", "do");
        alert(localStorage.removeItem(mod));
        
    } catch(e) {
        alert("No");
    }

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ***localStorage.getItem()*** function

or, ***localStorage["deducted"]***

```
function todaysExpenses(){
    var deducted = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("deducted"));
    var balance = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("balance"));
    document.getElementById("spent_points_today").innerHTML = deducted;
    document.getElementById("earned_points_today").innerHTML = balance;
    document.getElementById("balance-remaining").innerHTML = (balance - deducted);
    document.getElementById("balance-remaining-month").innerHTML = (balance - deducted);
}
```